# Vert.x - Get deployment ID within currently running verticle

Tags: vert.x

I'm looking for the deployment ID for the currently running verticle.

The goal is to allow a verticle to undeploy itself. I currently pass the deploymentID into the deployed verticle over the event bus to accomplish this, but would prefer some direct means of access.

> [container.undeployVerticle(deploymentID)](http://vertx.io/core_manual_java.html#undeploying-a-verticle-or-module)

Comment: Did my below answer help? Or do you need more elaboration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Somewhere in your desired verticle use this:
`context.deploymentID();`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 ways you can get the deployment id. If you have some verticle that starts and handles all the module deployments you can add an async result handler and then get the deployment id that way or you can get the platform manager from the container using reflection.

Async handler will be as follows:

```
container.deployVerticle("foo.ChildVerticle", new AsyncResultHandler<String>() {
public void handle(AsyncResult<String> asyncResult) {
    if (asyncResult.succeeded()) {
        System.out.println("The verticle has been deployed, deployment ID is " + asyncResult.result());
    } else {
        asyncResult.cause().printStackTrace();
    }
}
});
```

Access Platform Manager as follows:

```
 protected final PlatformManagerInternal getManager() {
 try {
   Container container = getContainer();
   Field f = DefaultContainer.class.getDeclaredField("mgr");
   f.setAccessible(true);
   return (PlatformManagerInternal)f.get(container);
 }
   catch (Exception e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
   throw new ScriptException("Could not access verticle manager");
 }
 }

 protected final Map<String, Deployment> getDeployments() {
 try {
    PlatformManagerInternal mgr = getManager();
    Field d = DefaultPlatformManager.class.getDeclaredField("deployments");
    d.setAccessible(true);
    return Collections.unmodifiableMap((Map<String, Deployment>)d.get(mgr));
  }
   catch (Exception e) {
      throw new ScriptException("Could not access deployments");
   }
  }
```

References:

- http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/io.vertx/vertx-platform/2.1.2/org/vertx/java/platform/impl/DefaultPlatformManager.java#DefaultPlatformManager.genDepName%28%29
- https://github.com/crashub/mod-shell/blob/master/src/main/java/org/vertx/mods/VertxCommand.java
- http://vertx.io/core_manual_java.html#deploying-a-module-programmatically